# Android: ClassNotFoundException trying to set custom typeface

Tags: android, fonts, layout-inflater

I'm using **[Foundry](https://bitbucket.org/josephearl/foundry)** library to set the custom typeface of the TextViews directly from the layout xml. I've tried the app in a Nexus 5 Android L and everything work ok but when I run the app in a HTC with Android 4.1.1 and Samsung Galaxy S3 Android 4.3 the app crashes. In the docs of the library say that I have to add the code below in the activity:

```
@Override
public Object getSystemService(final String name) {
    if (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
        return getFoundryLayoutInflater();
    }
    return super.getSystemService(name);
}

@Override
public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() {
    return getFoundryLayoutInflater();
}

private LayoutInflater getFoundryLayoutInflater() {
    if (foundryLayoutInflater == null) {
        foundryLayoutInflater = new FoundryLayoutInflater(this, new FoundryFoundry(getAssets(), "fonts"));
        foundryLayoutInflater.setFactory(this);
    }
    return foundryLayoutInflater;
}
```

I've seen if I comment that code the app does not crash inthe phones where previously crash. Below the stack trace of the crash on the Samsung Galaxy:

```
10-23 03:12:12.370  19441-19441/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activities.MyListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment, not found
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment, not found
            at android.view.AndroidLayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(AndroidLayoutInflater.java:88)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17862)
            at com.example.myapp.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:68)
            at com.example.myapp.activities.MyListActivity.onCreate(MyListActivity.java:50)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path: /data/app/com.example.myapp-1.apk
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
            at android.view.AndroidLayoutInflater.onCreateView(AndroidLayoutInflater.java:48)
            at uk.co.josephearl.foundry.AbstractCustomLayoutInflater.onCreateView(AbstractCustomLayoutInflater.java:29)
            at uk.co.josephearl.foundry.FoundryLayoutInflater.onCreateView(FoundryLayoutInflater.java:11)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.AndroidLayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(AndroidLayoutInflater.java:74)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17862)
            at com.example.myapp.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:68)
            at com.example.myapp.activities.MyListActivity.onCreate(MyListActivity.java:50)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: please post your xml